# How to toggle ng-hide and ng-show using two different controllers by sharing a factory toggle state instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular 1.x I am using two controllers and I want to show the controller_2 if the controller_1 is hidden. I am trying to use factory. 
Here is my html code:-

```
<div ng-controller="controller_1 as c1" ng-show="c1.state">
    <h1>{{ c1.value }}:-</h1>
    <button ng-click="c1.hide_and_show()">Click</button>
    <hr/>
</div>
<div ng-controller="controller_2 as c2" ng-hide="c2.state">
    <h1>{{ c2.value }}:-</h1>

</div>
```

When the user clicks the button the controller_1 part is hidden. However my controller_2 part is not showing up.
Here is my angular part:-

```
    app.factory('manage_state', function () {
        var data = {
           toggle: true
        };
        return data;
    });
    app.controller("controller_1", function($scope, manage_state) {
        this.value = "Controller 1";
        this.state = manage_state.toggle;
        this.hide_and_show = function(){
            manage_state.toggle = false;
            this.state = manage_state.toggle;                
        };
     });

     app.controller("controller_2", function($scope, manage_state) {
        this.value = "Controller 2";           
        this.state = manage_state.toggle;            
     });
```

Comment: They don't share state. Primitives cannot be passed by reference. `var a = 1; var b = a; a = 2; b !== a`.

Comment: So how do i get it working?

Comment: You can use `$scope.$broadcast` event from  controller 1 and listen it into controller 2.

Comment: any workaround without using $scope.

Comment: or $broadcast and $emit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitives cannot be passed by reference, so these controllers don't share state.

State should be an object:

```
this.state = manage_state;
```

And properties should be bound in view:

```
<div ng-controller="controller_1 as c1" ng-show="c1.state.toggle">
```